# Passing a substring (may contains quotes and so on) to a macro variable

Tags: sas

As we know, special characters should be masked during macro compilation. But what if I wanna assign a dynamic substring to a macro variable? Like this:

```
%let mvSubstr = %substr(&mvString, 1, 1);
```

`mvString` can contain any symbols including unmatched single or double quotation marks.

So, in this example program works correctly:

```
%lev mvString = Test;
%let mvSubstr = %substr(&mvString, 1, 1);
```

And in the following case program doesn't work and SAS reports `ERROR: Literal contains unmatched quote.`:

```
%lev mvString = %str(%'Test%');
%let mvSubstr = %substr(&mvString, 1, 1);
```

How can I defeat this problem (make program works independently of `mvString` value)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `%QSUBSTR()` function if you expect that it is possible the value of the substring will contain unmatched quotes or other characters that require macro quoting.  There is also the `%QSCAN()` function to use when the result of using `%SCAN()` might need quoting. And there is the `%QSYSFUNC()` function for when calling other SAS functions from within macro code.

Answer (score 3):

This is why [macro quoting](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002047063.htm) exists.  You have a lot of different options, depending on exactly what you're doing.

- `%quote`, `%nrquote`, `%bquote`, and `%nrbquote` - all do roughly the same thing: mask quote characters and some other special characters.  See for example the [documentation for `%bquote/nrbquote`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/z3514bquote.htm).  They tell SAS not to pay attention to `'` and similar, so it does not worry about matching things.  I've never seen a reason to use `%quote` over `%bquote` - the B stands for 'better' - so I would use that.  They work during *execution*, not *compilation*.  `%nrbquote` masks the macro characters `&` and `%`, meaning it will prevent a macro inside the macro variable from resolving.
- [`%str`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001061290.htm) and `%nrstr` mask during *compilation*.  Otherwise they are similar to `%bquote` and `%nrbquote`.  If it's important that it not have the quote during compilation, use these.
- [`%superq`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#tw3514-superq.htm) masks a macro *variable* only (not open text) and prevents all resolution from occurring.  It's often the best way to assign the value of one macro variable to another variable.  It importantly does not take the `&` - you pass the *name* of the macro variable, with no ampersands or whatnot (unless the name of the macro variable is stored in another macro variable).

In your case, you would need to use `%bquote` to quote the results of the substring assignment, so:

```
%let mvString = %str(%'Test%');
%put &=mvString;

%let mvSubstr = %bquote(%substr(&mvString, 1, 1));
%put &=mvString &=mvSubstr;
```

Comment: Sounds like a lot of extra work over just using the function that was built for this situation.

Comment: Not sure it's a lot of extra work (one macro statement?)... The `qsubstr` though is nice, I hadn't seen that yet.

Comment: `%QSUBSTR()` and `%QSCAN()` were part of the original handful of macro functions.  When they introduced `%SYSFUNC()` they included `%QSYSFUNC()` for the same reason.

Comment: Just a comment that %nrbquote doesn't actually prevent a macro reference from resolving. I think the NR is misleading, since it doesn't do the same thing as %nrstr.  Or it was just never programmed correctly, and instead of fixing it they added %superq. I'm away from SAS so can't provide an example. I have never found a good use for %nrbquote.  I think %str, %nrstr, %bquote and %superq are the full set of macro quoting functions one needs.

Answer (score 1):

What about the scenario where MVSTRING contains unmasked characters that need special treatment.  This requires quoting the argument of SUBSTR.

```
data _null_;
   call symputx('mvString',"'Test",'G');
   run;
%put %nrbquote(&=mvString);
%let mvSubstr = %bquote(%substr(%superq(mvString), 1, 1));
%put %nrbquote(&=mvString) %nrbquote(&=mvSubstr);
```

Comment: Agree - I had thought about mentioning that, but wanted to simplify my answer some. Definitely a good idea to consider the input as well (and a good example of the difference in the different quoting options).

Comment: That is a different situation. It would be nice if SAS had a data step function that could create a macro quoted macro variable.  For now you could add a %LET to apply the quoting after the data step has created it.

Comment: @Tom I think the `%superq` solution is superior - assume your data may not be properly quoted when writing your function/program and protect against that.  Separately quote it upon creation of course, but I don't think that's the point of DN's example here (that's just how he's getting an unquoted value in).

Comment: @Joe  It is actually pretty hard to get poorly quoted values into macro variables.  You can't pass them into parameters as the macro call will fail. You can't put them in via %LET as that will fail. The main loop hole is DATA _NULL_ and PROC SQL. But if you write a macro that references existing macro variables instead of parameters (or pass a macro variable by name instead of value) then you do need to code defensively.